# How to dual boot pop os and ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I had ubuntu linux on my system and wanted to install Pop os alongside ubuntu. Then I installed pop os and set the same boot partition that I had set for ubuntu in order to dual boot them. But now my system doesn't go to the grub menu to select my desired OS and automatically boot my new pop os.
I ran these commands to update grub but it didn't work:

```
os-prober
update-grub
```

What should I do now?
Thenk you in advance.

Comment: Assuming your Ubuntu version is 22.04. Is Pop OS mentioned in any menuentry of Ubuntu's /boot/grub/grub.cfg file? os-prober has been working for me when doing a `sudo update-grub`. contrary to what I have been told.

Comment: You should not share a /boot partition, but do share an ESP - efi system partition. And Pop uses SystemD boot as default but I understand you can install grub for it. Can you boot Pop directly from UEFI boot menu?

Answer (score 0):

**Pop OS** doesn't use **grub** for booting, instead it uses **systemd** to boot. So, you have to install **grub** to dual boot with **ubuntu**. Install **grub** using below command:

```
sudo apt install grub-efi grub-common grub-customizer
```

Now, install grub:

```
sudo grub-install
```

Now, update the grub to scan other operating systems:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

boot-repair worked for me with 22.04 and Pop!-OS: I followed the instructions from https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-repair-the-grub2-boot-loader-on-linux/